# Cannot find namespace Error when defining literal types with values from a constant

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type with values from a constant, I need those values in other parts of the code so really want to always reference the constants files. Typescript is throwing me the warning for both constants:

```
Cannot find namespace 'DIRECTION_TYPES'
```

And also seems to not be using the imports in the type definitions as I have this warning in the import:

```
All imports in import declaration are unused.
```

*constants.ts*

```
export const INPUT_TYPES = {
  forward: 'F',
  left: 'L',
  right: 'R',
} as const;

export const DIRECTION_TYPES = {
  north: 'N',
  south: 'S',
  east: 'E',
  west: 'W',
} as const;
```

*types/mower.d.ts*

```
import { INPUT_TYPES, DIRECTION_TYPES } from '../constants';

export type MowerInput =
    INPUT_TYPES.forward |
    INPUT_TYPES.left |
    INPUT_TYPES.right;

export type Direction =
    DIRECTION_TYPES.north |
    DIRECTION_TYPES.sotuh |
    DIRECTION_TYPES.east |
    DIRECTION_TYPES.west;

export type Position = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export type Mower = {
    direction: Direction;
    position: Position;
};
```

I really don't get what is it expected. How can I make it take the strings from constants?

Comment: You're trying to use a runtime VALUE as a TYPE.

Comment: You could export a type named the same thing as the constants and use them [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-zeh-8pf8bi?file=/src/mower.d.ts). Is this a satisfactory solution for you?